# Machine Learning Data Preprocessing with Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm new to machine learning. And I'm trying to using pandas/tensorflow to handle some data.
I know when I have data:

```
+----+------+
| ID | asset|
+----+------+
|  A | 1    |
|  B | 2    |
|  C | 3    |
|  D | 4    |
+----+------+
```

I can just get col "asset" as a list `[1,2,3,4]`, then transfer it to `[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]` using tensorflow.

But if I have data that looks like this:

```
+----+------+
| ID | asset|
+----+------+
|  A | 1    |
|  A | 2    |
|  A | 3    |
|  B | 1    |
+----+------+
```

And another table that looks like this:

```
+----+------+
| ID | debt |
+----+------+
|  D | 1    |
|  D | 2    |
|  D | 3    |
|  A | 1    |
+----+------+
```

That is to say, I have customer A that has 3 different types of assets and client D that has 3 different types of debts. Notice that client D does not even exist in the first table.

The 1st question is how I combine those tables to find matching clients with their assets/debts. Do I just join those tables? (in pandas `pd.merge()`)
In that way client D would have null values for assets. Or should I just pick clients that exist in every table? How should I do it?

The 2nd question is how can I transfer say table A to `[[1,1,1], [1,0,0]]`?

I hope the description makes sense. Correct me if I said anything wrong. Sorry for the long question :(

Comment: i just didn't understand the 2nd question if you could be more specific please ? thank you

Comment: Yes, from table A we can see that client A has assets type 1,2,3 and client B has type 1, so they will have a matrix representation of  `[[1,1,1],[1,0,0]]`. I was wondering how to get the matrix from table A.

Comment: I should mention that the data are all `csv` format, so table A would be one csv file, table B would be another one.

Comment: @BeyondRiver - I think a basic grasp of pandas is required long before attempting to start machine learning... It's like trying to learn accounting before understanding the role of money in a business.

Comment: @ Andrew L Thank you for the suggestion. I did have some practice in machine learning using prebuilt datasets. I have never encountered any situation where I had to prepare the data myself, and this is what I am trying to learn right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Question**:

The answer to that really depends on your machine learning problem and how you want to preprocess your data ( if you want to remove samples with missing data or impute them). Since this may be your first problem where you need to prepare your dataset, i recommend you have a look at [this](http://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/).

Now, if you decide you want to drop missing values, you could simply go ahead and do an `inner merge` like this one:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,"inner")
```

like that you will only be taking the intersection between `df1` and `df2`.

if you choose to impute missing values, do an `outer merge` like this one:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,"outer")
```

then you should be able to fill your missing values how ever you like (the proposed method in the link is one way to do it).

**Second Question**:

for this question, however, there may be a nicer method ( but i totally forgot its name if it exists indeed) but this should do just fine as well:

```
a = df1.groupby('ID')['asset'].unique()
# to have something like
#ID
#A    [1, 2, 4] 
#B          [1]

x = a.size
y = max([max(x) for x in a])
z = np.zeros((x,y))
# just instantiating the final matrix with the right shape and zeros
```

then you could use [numpy.put](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) to actually put `1's` in the right places like this:

```
for row in range(x):
    np.put(z[row],a[row]-1,1)
```

O/P ( for you example):

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

I hope this was helpful, if there are any questions or improvements please leave a comment.